# Неправильно считает нажатия на кнопку

Tags: java, gui

Пытаюсь сделать простенькую ролевую авторизацию, нужно чтоб при введении неправильно 3 раза пароля / логина закрывалось приложение, установил счетчик на actionPerformed , объявил count = 4; но считает как-то неправильно.

```
count = 3; - первое неправильное введение
count = 2; - второе неправильное введение
count = 0; - третье неправильно введение
```

Куда делась единица...

```
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
           count = count - 1;
           if (count == 0) {
           dispose();
      }
}
```

count сделал глобальной переменной, по умолчанию = 4

Дебаггером не могу пройтись, зависает намертво

Comment: Наверно, дело в том, что `actionPerformed` вызывается не только по нажатию на клавишу, а и при отпускании тоже. Добавьте вывод в лог в начале метода `actionPerformed` и вы это легко увидите

Comment: >но считает как-то неправильно. Как конкретно неправильно?? Больше раз нужно нажать или меньше? Или вообще не считает.

Comment: кажется у if нет закрывающей скобки (либо допишите, либо уберите существующую)

Comment: @Agzam4 когда копировал кусок кода случайно не вставил еще одну скобку .  Со скобками все ок

Comment: @RomanKonoval как можно решить? Mouse Listener (mousePressed) поможет решить ?